# How is this buffer really working?

Tags: c, linux, buffer

as a Linux system programming exercise I've written my own version of the tree command, which is to read from stdin and write to stdout using only the basic read() and write() C library functions. I've done it so that when an asterisk (*) is entered, the program is terminated. I have managed to get it to work properly, my problem is that I don't *really* understand why it works the way it does. What confuses me is the buffer. First of all, here is the code portion in question:

```
char buf[1];
...
do {
    read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1);
    if( buf[0] == '*') break;
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, 1);
} while( buf[0] != '*');
...
```

My idea was to read from stdin char by char, thereby storing the char in buf, check if it was an asterisk, then write the char from buf to stdout.

The behaviour is the following: I type a string of any number of chars, press ENTER, that string gets output to stdout, at which point I can type a new char string. If the string ends with an asterisk, the string is output up until the asterisk, then the program is terminated.

My problems are:

1) buf is sopposed to contain only one char. How is it possible that I enter any number of chars und upon pressing ENTER all of them are output to stdout? I would expect one char at a time to be output, or only the last one. How does a one-char buffer store all of those chars? Or do many one-char buffers get created? By whom?

2) What is so special about the newline character that prompts the string to be output? Why is it not just another char within the string? Is it just a matter of definition within the function read()?

Thank you for any help in understanding the working of the buffer!

Comment: The o/s is responsible for buffering what isn't buffered in your program. The newline character is given significance by the terminal driver; it's the indication to the terminal driver to make the previously entered information available to the rest of the I/O system. Until the newline is entered, the terminal driver (part of the O/S) is responsible for buffering the input. There's a maximum on what it's prepared to buffer, and that maximum can be quite small (256 characters perhaps; I've not checked what POSIX specifies as the minimum acceptable maximum). Newline has no significance in files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based upon the way the IO calls - read and write will work on most OS's.

You are reading only 1 byte, so while you are typing, stuff will be held by an io buffer (not yours), until your loop reads it. Since you have no sleeps, it will be reading, or waiting to read faster than you can humanly type.

Also as R Sahu suggests - the input buffer may not be presented to your program until you press enter on the console you are typing at. This depends on the console and its config - but most will buffer lines and wait for enter too. This would be different if you were piping into stdin.

The last parameter to read, the '1', is what instructs it to read one byte here.

The second part is that your output is also buffered, and newline is commonly used by console output buffers to flush and show the line. Until that case, it is being written by your code to that output buffer. If you do not want this behaviour, then an `fflush` call after the write should output character by character instead.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't consider there were more buffers than the one in my program!

Answer (score 1):

When you type in your input at a console, the input characters are not immediately fed to `stdin`. After you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button, the entire line you typed, including the newline character, are is fed to stdin by the run time environment.